# Is fibreglass dangerous?

Tags: sound-proofing, materials

I have recently been having problems with the sound in my room and somebody has suggested I use fibreglass to soundproof. Unfortunately the sound is entering through the window and so I thought of putting sheets of fibreglass in black bin liners up against the window. Will these fibreglass sheets (inside bin bags) be dangerous or irritant? What about if I moved them around in the bin bags (I.e. They weren't just leant up against the window)?
I'm worried that because it's not inside something more solid like a wall it may be give off fibres that could be irritant or in the worst case, cancerous?

Comment: There's a proper, semi-permanent, flexible (alternating between sound proofing and natural lighting) way to address this and there's all the other ways.  The proper way requires knowing the dimensions and details about the window and what can/should be safely done.  IE. are you renting, is the window a required emergency egress window, is it a basement apt. window, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Fiberglass insulation (the pink fluffy stuff) is a skin irritant and not great to breath either.  Keeping it in thick plastic garbage bags would be ok - unless the bags rip it you use really thin plastic bags.

A better idea would be styrofoam insulation.  It comes in big sheets you could cut to wedge perfectly in a window frame.  It does not have the same problems of being an irritant.